# Generate sequence of negative numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
    userId  firstName   lastName        gender          level
61  -1  Not Provided    Not Provided    Not Provided    paid
100 -1  Not Provided    Not Provided    Not Provided    free
```

Both `userId` are `-1` because I executed the code `user_df['userId'] = user_df['userId'].replace(r'^\s*$', '-1', regex=True)`.

Is possible to set sequential negative numbers like -1, -2, ...?

Comment: what are you counting by? index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want replace only empty strings use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for mask of this values and then add array with length by sum of `True`s in boolean mask:

```
user_df = pd.DataFrame({'userId':['','','qq','']})

m = user_df['userId'].str.contains(r'^\s*$')

user_df.loc[m, 'userId'] = -pd.np.arange(1, m.sum() + 1)
print (user_df)
.  userId
0     -1
1     -2
2     qq
3     -3
```

**Detail**:

```
user_df.loc[m, 'userId'] = -pd.np.arange(1, m.sum() + 1)
print (m)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: userId, dtype: bool

print (m.sum())
3

print (-pd.np.arange(1, m.sum() + 1))
[-1 -2 -3]
```

---

Also here is possible import numpy what is required for pandas:

```
import numpy as np

m = user_df['userId'].str.contains(r'^\s*$')

user_df.loc[m, 'userId'] = -np.arange(1, m.sum() + 1)
```

Comment: I don't have `np` package in udacity :(

Comment: @placplacboom - then use `-pd.np.`

Answer (score 3):

You can set negative sequential index numbers with the `range` function.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'userId': [-1, -1]}, index=[61, 100])
df.index = range(-1, -df.shape[0]-1 , -1)
```

Result:

```
    userId
-1      -1
-2      -1
```

Comment: but this changes the index and not the userId column right?

Comment: In order to change userId, use df['userId'] = range(-1, -df.shape[0]-1 , -1)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
user_df['userId'] = (df.index + 1) * -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
user_df['userId'] = (user_df['userId'].replace(r'^\s*$', -1, regex=True)
                     .groupby(user_df['userId']).cumsum())
```

Answer (score 2):

could also use a `groupby` and `subtract` with a `cumulative count`, I'm assuming your `userId` is already set to -1

```
df['userId'] = df['userId'].sub(df.groupby(['userId']).cumcount())
print(df)
       userId       firstName          lastName            gender     level
61       -1    Not Provided      Not Provided      Not Provided      paid
100      -2   Not Provided       Not Provided      Not Provided      free
```